# Mongo DB Cursor ID not valid at server

Tags: python, mongodb, cursor

I am querying a collection having about 4 million documents.

While looping over them with a python script i get always an error after about 5000 documents

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "geturl.py", line 16, in <module>
    for dict in  collection.find():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 814, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 776, in _refresh
    limit, self.__id))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 720, in __send_message
    self.__uuid_subtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 93, in _unpack_response
    cursor_id)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: cursor id '3664670275997321547' not valid at server
```

Is there something which I can do in the configuration ? Changing Batchsize ore something ?

Comment: looks like a good try thx, didn't found it myself , ill try it

Comment: Probably a better method than setting the timeout would be to check if that cursor is dead, most cursor objects have the method, and if it is dead then renew it.

Comment: maybe a combination without the timeout=false the cursor will be dead every time